# How to get themeDisplay after login and before landing page in liferay7.2

Tags: authentication, liferay, portlet, impersonation

I need to access themeDisplay in post login and before landing into a home page in liferay. I need to impersonate a user by another user's session, after login it should show the impersonated user home page.

Comment: Let explain better your case...

Comment: indeed... Liferay already implements impersonating other users - why reinvent the wheel? And if you really need to reinvent the wheel: Please provide us with what you've already done, what it does, what it should do, and the reason why you can't use the built-in functionality.

Comment: Hi, I need to get the themeDisplay in post login and before landing page. Actually I need to impersonate user by another after login. For example, if a group of users having parentcode. I am creating one more user with parent code and login with the parent user and giving option to select the user which is going to impersonate in login page itself. After login the parent user will be landing in the impersonated user home. Is there any action override to impersonate a user in post login and pre landing????

Comment: What's the purpose of all this? Impersonating a different user is quite a heavy-weight operation that means a lot of mischief can be done in the name of someone else. I'd say that whatever you want to do can probably be done in a less invasive way. Any clarification that you write, should be edited into your question (to make it clearer and more detailed), rather than into a comment.

Comment: Okay. We have customer login. There are multiple user login under same customer. Like one customer having multiple account in a site. He want to login at once. and he can see the content for all the user account without logout login again. For all the accounts he having unique key called parentKey. So we have created one more user with the parentKey like parent account and he can login using the parent account. but there is no content for parent account.

Comment: .... We have given a select option in login so that he can select any one child account so that he can land on the selected child account personal page. And also we have given one more select option in the landing page so that he can switch the child accounts. For that we are trying to do impersonation for child accounts. We have done for landing page switch but while login we are not getting.

Comment: It is not clear what "getter" of the ThemeDisplay you need.
But I have retrieved a lot of stuff that is in ThemeDisplay with the PortalUtil.

i.e. to get the groupId
PortalUtil.getScopeGroupId(lifecycleEvent.getRequest());